# How to parse incoming stream where one piece determines another's interpretation in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, types, enums, stream

So I have to parse a header on a message, where one byte of the header determines how the next byte is interpreted.  All interpretations can be represented as enums.  What I've got so far (simplified):

```
enum MsgType { NOP, MSG_A, MSG_B, MSG_C; } // The type of the first byte
enum AInterp { FOO, BAR; }                 // Interpretation of 2nd byte if 1st byte is MSG_A
enum BInterp { ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA; }       // " " " if 1st byte is MSG_B
enum CInterp { ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR; }    // " " " if 1st byte is MSG_C
AInterp a = null;
BInterp b = null;
CInterp c = null;
```

Each enum has a method enumVal() that returns the **enumeration** for the value of a byte, or null if there isn't one, but for this question we'll just use valueOf().
The incoming stream contains the header where one piece determines how to interpret the next piece. Reading from a ByteBuffer BB:

```
MsgType m          = MsgType.valueOf(BB.get());
byte    secondByte = BB.get();
switch (m)
{
    case NOP:       /* no options */             break;
    case MSG_A: a = AInterp.valueOf(secondByte); break;
    case MSG_B: b = BInterp.valueOf(secondByte); break;
    case MSG_C: c = CInterp.valueOf(secondByte); break;
    default:        /* no options /*             break;
}
```

I know there are try/catch blocks missing, but you get the point.
This gets very cumbersome very quickly.  To ask for a, b, or c's value, I have to know the value of m, which just defeats the purpose.

I'd LIKE to be able to somehow make a single variable for the 2nd byte, and cast it to the type of enumeration that would be appropriate, something like:

```
genericEnum x = null;
MsgType     m = MsgType.valueOf(BB.get());
(typeCastingFrom(m)) x = (typeCastingFrom(m)).valueOf(BB.get())
```

So I'd need some inheritance scheme for enumerations, I think.
But Java doesn't allow that.
I'll end up just storing the 2nd byte as a byte, I think, and interpreting it when I need to based on m.
Anybody have a more elegant solution?

Comment: You could add an `abstract` method to `MsgType` and then have each value in the enum override it. Once you've read the second byte, you could then invoke the enum value's abstract method. I can write up an answer with more information, if you'd like.

Comment: @Jacob G. I'd love to see an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Java’s `enum` types support abstraction through interfaces. So you can declare

```
interface Interp {
    String name(); // exists automatically when implemented as enum
    // define common operations
}
enum MsgType { // The type of the first byte
    NOP, MSG_A, MSG_B, MSG_C;
    static MsgType valueOf(byte b) {
        return null;
    }
}
enum AInterp implements Interp {// Interpretation of 2nd byte if 1st byte is MSG_A
    FOO, BAR;
    static AInterp valueOf(byte b) {
        return null;
    }
}
enum BInterp implements Interp {// " " " if 1st byte is MSG_B
    ALPHA, BETA, GAMMA;
    static BInterp valueOf(byte b) {
        return null;
    }
}
enum CInterp implements Interp {// " " " if 1st byte is MSG_C
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR;
    static CInterp valueOf(byte b) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

To handle them uniformly, you can prepare a lookup data structure like

```
interface InterpFactory {
    Interp get(byte b);
}
static final Map<MsgType,InterpFactory> KNOWN;
static {
    Map<MsgType,InterpFactory> m = new EnumMap<>(MsgType.class);
    m.put(MsgType.NOP, b -> null);
    m.put(MsgType.MSG_A, AInterp::valueOf);
    m.put(MsgType.MSG_B, BInterp::valueOf);
    m.put(MsgType.MSG_C, CInterp::valueOf);
    KNOWN = Collections.unmodifiableMap(m);
}
```

which can be used as simple as

```
MsgType m = MsgType.valueOf(BB.get());
Interp x = KNOWN.get(m).get(BB.get());
```